# How to resolve JSON parse error in Google Colab

Tags: json, google-colaboratory, jsonparser

I'm trying to upload a custom module .py file in Google Colab. However, I get a parse error as follows.

Error:

> Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 2 (line 1
> column 3) SyntaxError: Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON
> at position 2 (line 1 column 3)
> at JSON.parse ()
> at ua.program_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/cce4fce8bbe78d8bdc0c77a288df9fa7/external_polymer_binary.js:3899:262)
> at wa (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/cce4fce8bbe78d8bdc0c77a288df9fa7/external_polymer_binary.js:16:57)
> at ua.next_ (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/cce4fce8bbe78d8bdc0c77a288df9fa7/external_polymer_binary.js:14:195)
> at laa.next (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/cce4fce8bbe78d8bdc0c77a288df9fa7/external_polymer_binary.js:17:48)
> at b (https://ssl.gstatic.com/colaboratory-static/common/cce4fce8bbe78d8bdc0c77a288df9fa7/external_polymer_binary.js:17:309)

I'm very naive to JSON-related topic. Any help in this regard is highly valued.